# Conversion of text to propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am having a bit of a trouble converting this expression to propositional logic form.

Say for example, the following symbols represent the following conditions.

A - Alpha comes to the meeting 
B - Bravo Comes to the meeting 
C - Charlie comes to the meeting 
D - Delta comes to the meeting  
E - Echo comes to the meeting.

I want to represent the following statements into propositional logic

1. Alpha comes to the meeting provided that Delta does not come, but if Delta does comes to the meeting, then Charlie does not come to the meeting.
2. Charlie, Alpha, and Echo come to the meeting if and only if Bravo does not come, but if neither Charlie nor Alpha came, then Bravo comes only if Echo comes to the meeting.

Here is my solution, but I have a feeling it's not the right way. Due to the fact that English is not my first language, I have much trouble trying to make sense

1. (A  → ¬D) ∧ (D  → ¬C)
2. ((C∧ A∧ E) ↔ ¬B ) ∧((¬C ∧¬A  ∧ E)) ↔ B)

Is this an acceptable method, or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: For 2, the left conjunct is Ok, but I think that the right one is not.

Comment: If (neither C nor A), then (B only if E). It seems to me that must be: (¬C ∧¬A) → (B → E).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some errors:
you should have $(\lnot D \rightarrow A)$ instead of $(A \rightarrow \lnot D)$ the first line.

And $((\lnot C \land \lnot A)\rightarrow (E \leftrightarrow B))$ instead of ((¬C ∧¬A ∧ E)) ↔ B)

My advice here is for implications if you see "if A then B" or "B provided/if A" then you have $(A \rightarrow B)$ this seems to be what is tripping you up.

Comment: No, "Alpha comes to the meeting provided that Delta does not come," means *both* that if Delta comes, then Alpha does not, and if Delta does not, then Alpha does.  $(D\to \neg A)\wedge(\neg D\to A)$ or $A\leftrightarrow \neg D$

Comment: I can kind of see this either way, but I think you are right